# How to hide a column in grid (GeneXus Evo 3)

Tags: genexus

how can i hide a grid column in GeneXus Evo 3? There is no more the columns property if I click on the grid!

In Evo 1 and 2 I know how to do this but in Evo 3 the optioin is gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top left corner of the grid should allow you to right-click and select the `"Columns..."` item of the menu.

Alternatively you can click on the desired column, then press `F4` to show the column properties.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast :) Your answer is perfect for non responsive grids. In case of responsive grids I found the solution: right click on the grid, then selecting the option responsive size. In this window I can hide a column for every screen size. Thanks again.